# Filling blank column space with 0

Tags: python, numpy, replace, zero

I am trying to replace a blank column space in my txt file with 0.

1. 2 6
2. 4 8
3. 6

I tried the following approach.

```
import numpy as np
data=np.loadtxt('/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/A_1.txt')
data[data==''] = '0'
```

Received this: ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 3.

My values are not comma separated, so I tried the following also.

```
data[data== ] = 0
```

In this instant the error received was different: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

My expected output is like:

1. 2 6
2. 4 8
3. 6 0

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `data[data==''] = '0'` or `data[data==] = '0'` to do? The `data==` variation is indeed invalid syntax, the `data==''` variation is effectively the same as `data[False] = '0'`

Comment: I assumed it would replace the blank space with 0 because I have worked with something like this: 1: Bad_val = np.where(data== -1E20) 2: data[Bad_val] = np.nan where all such values equaling  -1E20 were replaced by nans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) docs suggest (in the notes):

> This function aims to be a fast reader for simply formatted files. The [`genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) function provides more sophisticated handling of, e.g., lines with missing values.

However, handling of "missing values" in [`genfromtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) and replacing them with the "filler values" is possible only for a known "missing value", for example `x` in place of a number.

That's not your case. You have a file with missing fields and these `numpy` methods just can't handle it. You could parse and load the file manually, or, if that's acceptable, use [`pandas.read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_table.html), like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.read_table('/path/to/file', dtype=float, header=None, sep='\s+').fillna(0).values
array([[ 2.,  6.],
       [ 4.,  8.],
       [ 6.,  0.]])
```

The `read_table()` will replace missing values with `NaN`s, and we can replace them with zeros, with [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method. The underlaying `numpy.array` is accessible with `.values`.